# how to insert html table data per tr into sql table

Tags: php, html, sql

here is my following code, I want to insert html table data per row into sql, but using this code, only store last trow to database table, I think I need to use loop to read the data per trow, not only last trow, any ideas?

```
 <?php
    //connect
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){


    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","Matt","password");
       if (!$con){
           die("Can not connect: " . mysql_error());
       }
       mysql_select_db("propereva",$con);

      INSERT INTO properevatables (Number, Name,BasicSalary,ServiceMonths,SalaryPercentWithoutCEO,SalaryPercentWithCeo,PercentEvaShareByCeoDirectReports,PercentEvaShareByCeoAndDirectReports,PercentKpi,EvaBonusInMonths,percentwithbank,TotalEvaBonus,totalwithbank) VALUES ('$_POST[number]','$_POST[membername]','$_POST[salary]','$_POST[service]','$_POST[percentwithoutCEO]','$_POST[percentwithCEO]','$_POST[ceoReport]','$_POST[directresult]','$_POST[kpi]','$_POST[resultpercentageEVA]','$_POST[percentwithbank]','$_POST[yearonly]','$_POST[totalwithbank]')";


       mysql_query($sql,$con);

       mysql_close($con);
     }

     ?>
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML that posts the data?

Comment: pls provide working code including the html and specify what error or output you got.

Comment: it is actually a simple  table which consist of 10 trows
the problem is it shall read every trows data, not only last trows
<table>
<tr>

<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is send the data of an entire table to the server for storage.

You can do this using JavaScript and collate all the data into a JSON Object to send to the server using an AJAX request.

You can learn about AJAX in JavaScript from

here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

or you can chose to use a JavaScript library such as JQuery to help you with your AJAX needs.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

You can also use HTML inputs within the table to submit all the values however this is not recommended.

Comment: umm, what I need is to store data to sql, would it works?

Comment: The method you are doing with input fields in every cell would work as long as you give each input element a name using the name attribute. It sounds to me like you need to learn how to use HTML forms and submit them to the back end 
 so why dont you give this tutorial a go first?

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Yup, I have read it, 
 the problem is, I can store the data from my table using my code above, but it only stores the data from the last  table rows.
so actually what I need is, I need some php code suggestion to stores my table data which can read every row, like using loop or array or something else? 
thank you very much by the way :D

Comment: OK well if you are going to do it this way then you need to name each input field accordingly. So for example if you have 10 rows then you need to name the first row of the input fields as salary-1, member-1 etc... And for row 2 then you need salary-2, member-2 etc... Then on your PHP you would loop through the post variables from member-1 through to member-10. E.g. $_POST['member-' . i ] **But please note, this is not the correct way to do this! ** It is not future proof and results in lots of post variables. You should be learning how to use AJAX to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$number=$_POST['Number'];
$name=$_POST['Name'];
$salary=$_POST['BasicSalary'];
$service=$_POST['ServiceMonths'];

$insert=mysql_query("insert into `properevatables ` (Number,Name,BasicSalary,ServiceMonths) values('$number','$name','$salary','$service')");

if($insert)
{
    $msg="Inserted Successfully";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script>";

}
else
{
$msg=" Insert Not Successfully";
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$msg');</script>";

}

}
?>
```

By this you can add more fields.I added only three as of now.Here the connect.php is the connection file to the database.You can either use separate file else include he connection code in the same file.

Comment: umm, I don't have any problem in adding more fields to my database
my problem is I need to store all of my table data to my database
which consist of 10 <tr> and within each tr is consist of 13 <td> 

if you can see my code above, I could insert data, but it only insert the last row (last <tr>)